# Python split string every n char

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, join, python-2.x

I want to split a string every n char and the print must be like that:

```
MISSISSIPPI => MI*SS*IS*SI*PP*I
```

I've done a program but I don't know how to change the `,` with a `*`. Here is the code:

```
n=input('chunk size')
s=input('Add word')
import re
r=[s[i:i+n] for i in range(0, len(s), n)]
print (r)
```

This is the output:

```
['MI', 'SS', 'IS', 'SI', 'PP', 'I']
```

but I want it to be like this:

```
MI*SS*IS*SI*PP*I
```

Comment: Do you actually want the brackets in the output?

Answer (score 2):

You could use `str.join()` for this:

```
>>> '*'.join(r)
'MI*SS*IS*SI*PP*I'
```

What this does is iterate over the strings in `r`, and join them, inserting `'*'`.

Answer (score 2):

you could also use `re` module:

```
import re

r = '*'.join(re.findall('..|.$', s))
```

Output:

```
'MI*SS*IS*SI*PP*I'
```

Answer (score 2):

Well at the point that you're at, you just have 1 more line to add:

```
r = '*'.join(r)
```

So then your program becomes

```
n=input('chunk size')
s=input('Add word')
import re
r=[s[i:i+n] for i in range(0,len(s),n)]
r = '*'.join(r)
print (r)
```

Answer (score 1):

Unpack it and then use a custom separator:

```
>>> print(*r, sep='*')
MI*SS*IS*SI*PI
```

If you want the brackets in the output, use string formatting instead.

```
>>> print('[{}]'.format('*'.join(r)))
[MI*SS*IS*SI*PI]
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use split and join methods of string data structure.

`x = 'MI*SS*IS*SI*PP*I'` 
`xlist = x.split('*')`
`'*'.join(xlist)`